# How to implement a Field Value Transformer in Sitecore 9 Data Exchange Framework

Tags: sitecore

I want to implement the **Sitecore Data Exchange Framework 2.0** in Sitecore 9, but I was wondering if anyone has already some experience with implementing a **Field Value Transformer**.

The purpose is to import data from an xml file into Sitecore (items).

I read the Sitecore DEF tutorial http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v1.4.1/getting-started/index.html but couldn't find any example of that.

The simple import was already a success (field mapping one to one)

But there are some other things I want to do like:

- Transform values to **lowercase** + **replacing spaces** in my target field value
- **Import an image** based on the URL in the source object and save it in the Image field on the target item.
- **Build a complete URL** in the target field value based on a 2 other fields (language and id) (Ex: language = 'nl' and id = 123 => https://www.mywebsite.com/[language]/product/[id]

I'm pretty new to Sitecore so maybe the Field Value Transformer is not the best practice. Any suggestions are welcome.